# Google plus showing <p>-*+</p> on share

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-one

When users share page/url on blogs it shows `<p>-*+</p>` in description.
I have placed all meta tags required and other sites like facebook are working fine. this problem is only with G+ share.
Meta tags included are as follows

```
<meta property="og:title" content="My title" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://mysiteurl.com/blog.jpg" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://mysiteurl.com/blog" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Content description" />
```

Comment: What is the problem with this question, someone downvoted and flaged to close without any reason.

Comment: You don't include enough info. At a minimum you should include HTML snippets of the various tags Google+ uses to populate the share dialog. The best thing would be a link to a live example.

Comment: Then comments can be used to mention this if it dont include required info, and there is a edit feature available to edit it later if anybody comments and ask for more info. I am not arguing , this is what i think it should work.

Comment: Anyways I just updated question with meta tags used

Comment: Meta tags don't show anything unusual, so it's unlikely that anyone will be able to provide an answer without seeing a live example.

Comment: Ultimately its resolved, issue was with other functions modifying description. some of them was modified unusually to `<p>-*+</p>`. Just had to do some changes to render description properly.